# angularjs: how does the replace attribute works for directive ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to figure out how the 'replace' attribute work for directive. I've run into a scenario when setting it to true was causing my code to break.

The directive:

```
 angular.module('cdt.dm.directives').directive('referenceFiles', [
function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/dm/views/templates/referenceFiles/referenceFiles.html',
        scope: {
            job: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            scope.deleteReferenceFile = function (id) {
                scope.job.references.splice(id, 1);
            }

        }
    }
}]);
```

the referenceFiles.html template:

```
<div class="grid-action-filter" popover-placement="left" popover-template="app/dm/views/templates/referenceFiles/simple.html">
<span class="badge" style="cursor:pointer" >{{job.references.length}} added</span>
```

the simple.html template used by the popover directive:

```
<span>{{job.references.length}} reference files</span>
<table ng-repeat="ref in job.references">
  <tr>
    <td>{{ref.name}}</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn grid-button btn-danger" ng-click="deleteReferenceFile($index);"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If I set replace to true in the referenceFiles directive, then the deleteReferenceFile method won't be found on the scope when clicking the button. Instead I have to call it this way:

```
$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.deleteReferenceFile($index)
```

needless to say, it's ugly...

If I remove the replace attribute of the directive, then everything works fine.

Could someone explain this behaviour ?

Comment: Try to use one root container in simple.html template. I got some problems when tried to replace element with several root elements.

Comment: I've surrounded all the elements with a DIV element in simple.html but that leads to the same problem when using replace=true.  Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: and the same for referenceFiles.html (wrap to a div element). Also I'm not sure why do you use array as the second argument into directive try use just function.

Comment: don't think you need isolated sccope, try commenting it out, then scope will be that of closest parent scope,

Comment: where do you use the `reference-file` directive?